# How to obtain and serve Vertx SockJS eventbus javascript client dependency

Tags: java, gradle, vert.x, sockjs

Vertx [Web JSock Documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge) says that in order to bridge sock JS to eventbus one would use `vertx-eventbus.js` in client javascript. The stated gradle dependency to obtain this file is:

`compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.4.1:client'`

However that dependency is not found by gradle in jCenter and/or mavenCentral repos where other vertx dependencies reside.

My questions:

1) How does one properly obtain `vertx-eventbus.js` in java server-side gradle project?

2) Once dependency is resolved, how to serve `vertx-eventbus.js` from classpath via http server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dowload the event-bus JS librabry from CDN:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vertx